# BigQuery converts automatically a string into int

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a field called `field_string` of type `string`. I insert data in json format and some rows have only numbers for that field. For example `"field_string": "123456"`. The problem is that BigQuery transforms the value of that row into `int` and cannot insert it because the types do not match. I cannot transform the field's type because some rows do have letters or symbols in that field.

I have a workaround that adds a symbol to the string so that BigQuery does not convert it, but I would like to know whether I can find a way to not do that.

The job configuration is the following:

```py
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        autodetect=False,
        write_disposition=bigquery.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
        source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
        max_bad_records=10,
        ignore_unknown_values=False,
    )
```

Thanks!

Comment: Consider adding a schema to your job_config:  https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas#python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @rtenha in the comment, you should pass the schema inside your LoadJobConfig. Below is the same for a sample schema.

```
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
   schema=[
       bigquery.SchemaField("id", "STRING"),
       bigquery.SchemaField("field_string", "STRING"),
   ],
   autodetect=False,
   source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON
)
```

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you!